# Узнать баланс биткойн кошелька в C#

Tags: c#, .net, bitcoin, криптовалюта

В вебе есть куча апи\сайтов, которые показывают баланс на биткойн кошельках. Подскажите пожалуйста, как они это делают?
Я пробовал запускать у себя rpc (в тестовом режиме) и с помощью json запроса:

```
{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "curltest", "method": "getreceivedbyaddress", "params": ["tb1qerae08lsry6k6xc08pvemp6z6m66kjamxnk59q", 6]}
```

Я вижу баланс своего кошелька, но если я хочу запросить баланс другого кошелька, то мне баланс не показывает, пока я не ввожу команду importaddress, но при этом мне надо будет запустить Bitcoin Core, он долго, долго думает, после чего я смогу видеть баланс данного кошелька. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно с помощю C# узнать баланс любого кошелька без долгих ожиданий? Как понимаю Bitcoin Core это база данных транзакций, можно ли как-то читать данную базу, либо перелить данные в обычную базу? Как вообще делают другие (например сайты на которых можно посмотреть баланс)?

Comment: Вероятно, взять все данные, просчитать их у себя и писать в базу по мере вычисления. Ну а потом только докидывать новые блоки и пересчитывать.

Comment: Не подскажете, есть ли такая практика?

Comment: Понятия не имею.

Comment: Отличный вариант @Qwertiy, но естественно этих кошельков огромное множество подумайте надо ли оно Вам. Если же мы говорим о крупных сайтах, им легко так делать, ресурсы и хранилище довольно большое. Других вариантов получение баланса у Вас нет, так устроен биткоин. Также сделайте задержку на обновление других кошельков, поскольку не факт чтобы блоки приходящие к Вам правильные, достаточно сделать её на 4-5 блоков

Comment: @artemgh, мне вообще ничего не надо - не я же спросил. В любом случае, кошельков намного меньше, чем вся история операций, так что вполне логично её просто просчитать, а хранить только несколько последних блоков.

Comment: @Qwertiy я имел ввиду что у Вас хороший вариант, а дальше уже обращался к **Voucik**, видимо не так написал)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поискал в интернете *(уж очень люблю биток)*. Всё таки наилучшим для Вас будет использовать собственную БД, если не хотите Api.

По не совсем точным подсчётам, она будет весить ~27гб, но это сильно зависит от способа их хранения. Также как говорил ранее, не доверяйте блоку сразу, ждите ещё несколько.

Не нашёл ещё каких-либо способов (конечных), посчитать можно только так, да и вообще это внутреннее устройство Bitcoin. Думаю этот способ является нормальным, при условии грамотного хранения данных.

Насчёт чтения этой бд, стоит понимать что это не база балансов, а всё таки база ключей, которые отображают транзакции, и в конечном счёте чтобы убедится насчёт Вашего баланса, надо просмотреть все транзакции, которых очень много, поэтому такая скорость.

Comment: Почему ответ общий?

Comment: Я также использовал Вашу идею о бд @Qwertiy

Comment: Ну и что? Всё равно можно было авторским делать.

Comment: @Qwertiy хорошо, учту, спасибо